# onClickListener in ListFragment not responding

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment

Confused as to why the onClickListener is not responding. Is it because but buttons are set in one layout, but bound to another one? Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class ActivityList extends ListFragment

{
private ActivityDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private Long mRowId=Long.valueOf(1);
private Activity mContext; //changed to private
AlertDialog activity_relationship;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mContext=this.getActivity();
mDbHelper=new ActivityDbAdapter(mContext);
mDbHelper.open();
Cursor activity = mDbHelper.fetchAll(mRowId);
View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_activity_row, container,false);
Button relationship = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.show_relationship_activities);




String[] from = new String[]{ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_VALUE1_RELATIONSHIP , //from and too.
        ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_VALUE1_EDUCATION,
        ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_VALUE1_RECREATION,
        ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_VALUE1_MIND, ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_VALUE1_DAILY};


int[] to = new int[]{R.id.relationship_value,R.id.education_value, R.id.recreation_value,
        R.id.mind_value, R.id.daily_value};

SimpleCursorAdapter contacts = 
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(mContext, R.layout.activity_activity_row, activity, from, to); //my cursor adapter 


relationship.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg) {

        Log.e("Why","Are you not working?");

        Cursor activity = mDbHelper.fetchAll(mRowId);

     String mactivity_relationship=activity.getString(                                              //define all of the Strings. Gahh!!
            activity.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ActivityDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_ACTIVITY1_RELATIONSHIP));

        AlertDialog activity_relationship=new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create();
        activity_relationship.setTitle("Relationship Activities");
        String activities=(mactivity_relationship+"\n"+mactivity_relationship2+"\n"+mactivity_relationship3+
                "\n"+mactivity_relationship4+"\n"+mactivity_relationship5);
        activity_relationship.setMessage(activities);
        activity_relationship.show();



    }

});

setListAdapter(contacts);




return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_activity_list, container, false);

}

}
```

As I have it right now, the log is not even showing up.

Comment: Please post your `activity_activity_row.xml` layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to return the view that you actually create(and use for getting the `Button`) in the `onCreateView`:

```
//...
return view;
```

instead of returning a newly inflated layout(and losing the previous `Button`):

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_activity_list, container, false);
```

Or add the `view` to a view from the `R.layout.activity_activity_list` file that you inflate and return.

Comment: Figured that was it. Just wanted to make sure before I headed down another path. Will accept as soon as I can. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sam Judging by your code... are you trying to set a `OnClickListener` for the `Buttons` from the list rows? If yes, don't do this, you'll need to make a custom adapter and set the `OnClickListener` in the `getView` method(or `bindView` for Cursor based adapters) method.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do. I'll do that. Thanks again.